# Changing values dynamically in python from a file

Tags: python, variables, dynamic

I have a class that works with various values, and another that reads values from an external file. I need the other one to replace the values of the values class with the values taken from the file. Is there a way to do this?

I guess I could submit my code here, but I don't think it'll be of much help because it's in my mother language and it involves a lot of parameters you're not familiar with.

The large number values you see are the values I need to change.

```
class Properties:
'''Calculates the amount of insurance and/or remedies for a person
when given a certain set of parameters.
'''
def input(self, kt, aldur, heimilisfang, busetutimi, maki, born, sjomennska,
tekjur, ororkuhlutfall, ororkualdur, frestun_ellilifeyris,
byr_einn, bifreidarstyrkur):
    self.kt = kt
    self.aldur = aldur
    self.heimilisfang = heimilisfang
    self.maki = maki
    self.born = born
    self.busetutimi = busetutimi
    self.sjomennska = sjomennska
    self.tekjur = tekjur
    self.ororkuhlutfall = ororkuhlutfall
    self.ororkualdur = ororkualdur
    self.frestun_ellilifeyris = frestun_ellilifeyris
    self.byr_einn = byr_einn
    self.bifreidarstyrkur = bifreidarstyrkur

    #Ororkulifeyrir reiknadur.

    baetur = 0
    ororkustyrkur = 25175
    ororkustyrkur_62 = 34053
    ororkulifeyrir = 408636/12
    ellilifeyrir = 408636/12                            #Deilt med 12 thvi thetta a ad vera manadarlega.

    if aldur < 67 and ororkuhlutfall >= 75 and not sjomennska:           #Reiknar ororku.
        baetur = baetur + ororkulifeyrir
        print "-1 Ororkulifeyrir. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s." % baetur

    if 18 < aldur < 62 and 50 <= ororkuhlutfall < 75 and tekjur < 2575220 and aldur < 67:
        baetur = baetur + ororkustyrkur
        print "-1 Ororkustyrkur. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s." % baetur
    elif 18 < aldur < 62 and 50 <= ororkuhlutfall< 75 and 2575220 < tekjur < 4209764/12:
        baetur = baetur + ororkustykur*0.75
        print "-1 Skertur ororkustyrkur. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s." % baetur
    else:
        print "-1 Enginn ororkustyrkur."

    if 62 <= aldur and 50 <= ororkuhlutfall < 75 and not sjomennska:
        baetur = baetur + ororkustyrkur_62
        print "-1 Ororkustyrkur 62 ara og eldri. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s." % baetur

    #Ellilifeyrir, tekjutrygging, barnalifeyrir og aldurstengd ororkuuppbot reiknud.

    if sjomennska:
        print "Sjomennska valin."
        if busetutimi < 40 and aldur >= 60:
            ellilifeyrir = ellilifeyrir * busetutimi/40
            print "0 Busetuskertur ellilifeyrir."

        if 75 <= ororkuhlutfall:
            if 2575220/12 < tekjur < 4209764/12 and  aldur >= 67:
                ellilifeyrir = ellilifeyrir * 0.75  #Ellilifeyrir skerdist um 25%
                baetur = baetur + ellilifeyrir
                print "1 Skertur ellilifeyrir. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
            elif tekjur < 2575220/12 and aldur >= 67:
                baetur = baetur + ellilifeyrir
                print "1 Oskertur ellilifeyrir. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
            else:
                print "1 Enginn ellilifeyrir."

            if aldur >= 67 and tekjur > 1315200/12:
                tekjutrygging = 1289528/12           #Tekjutrygging manadarlega
                baetur = baetur + tekjutrygging * (1-0.3835)
                print "2 Skert tekjutrygging fyrir ellilifeyristhega. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
            elif aldur >= 67 and not tekjur > 2575220/12:
                tekjutrygging = 1289528/12
                baetur = baetur + tekjutrygging
                print "2 Oskert tekjutrygging fyrir ellilifeyristhega. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
            else:
                print "2 Engin tekjutrygging fyrir ellilifeyristhega."

        # if skipunin her ad ofan er naudsynleg thvi utreikningurinn er mismunandi eftir thvi hvort
        # sjomadurinn er fullur oryrki eda ekki. Ef hann er fullur oryrki er gert rad fyrir ad hann vilji
        # vera oryrki til 67 ara aldurs thvi baetur oryrkja eru haerri en baetur ellilifeyristhega.

        else:
            if 2575220/12 < tekjur < 4209764/12 and  aldur >= 60:
                ellilifeyrir = ellilifeyrir * 0.75  #Ellilifeyrir skerdist um 25%
                baetur = baetur + ellilifeyrir
                print "1 Skertur ellilifeyrir. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
            elif tekjur < 2575220/12 and aldur >= 60:
                baetur = baetur + ellilifeyrir
                print "1 Oskertur ellilifeyrir. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
            else:
                print "1 Enginn ellilifeyrir."

            if aldur >= 60 and tekjur > 1315200/12:
                tekjutrygging = 1289528/12           #Tekjutrygging manadarlega
                baetur = baetur + tekjutrygging * (1-0.3835)
                print "2 Skert tekjutrygging fyrir ellilifeyristhega. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
            elif aldur >= 60 and not tekjur > 2575220/12:
                tekjutrygging = 1289528/12
                baetur = baetur + tekjutrygging

                print "2 Oskert tekjutrygging fyrir ellilifeyristhega. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
            else:
                print "2 Engin tekjutrygging fyrir ellilifeyristhega."

        if 75 <= ororkuhlutfall and aldur <= 67 and tekjur < 2575220/12:
            tekjutrygging = 1308604/12
            baetur = baetur + tekjutrygging
            print "3 Oskert tekjutrygging fyrir oryrkja. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
        elif 75 <= ororkuhlutfall and aldur <= 67 and 2575220/12 < tekjur < 4209764/12:
            tekjutrygging = 1308604/12
            baetur = baetur + tekjutrygging * (1-0.3835)
            print "3 Skert tekjutrygging fyrir oryrkja. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
        else:
            print "3 Engin tekjutrygging fyrir oryrkja."

        if 75 <= ororkuhlutfall and aldur <= 67 and born > 0:
            barnalifeyrir = 25175
            baetur = baetur + barnalifeyrir * born
            print "4 Barnalifeyrir oryrkja. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
        else:
            print "4 Enginn barnalifeyrir oryrkja."

        # Naudsynlegt er ad adili bui einn til ad eiga rett a heimilisuppbot.
        # Heimilisuppbot er skert likt og tekjutrygging.

        frestunartugabrot = frestun_ellilifeyris / 200

        # Frestunartugabrotid er notad i linunni her a eftir. Deilt er med 2 thvi baeturnar eru haekkadar
        # um 0,5% fyrir hvern frestunarmanud. Deilt er med 100 til ad fa ut tugabrot.

        baetur = baetur + baetur * frestunartugabrot

        # Baetur eru haekkadar i hlutfalli vid frestunartugabrot og thar med fjolda frestunarmanada.

        # Frestun ellilifeyris. Gert er rad fyrir ad allir sjomenn vilji 1) Ororkulifeyri til 67 ara aldurs,
        # thvi ad baeturnar eru haerri hja oryrkjum en ellilifeyristhegum vegna aldurstengdrar ororkuuppbotar,
        # og 2) Fresta ellilifeyri um 5 ar thvi their munu hafa ororkulifeyri fram til 67 ara aldurs.

        for item in aldurstengd_ororka.keys():
            for age in item:
                if ororkualdur == age and aldur < 67 and 75 <= ororkuhlutfall:
                    baetur = baetur + ororkulifeyrir * aldurstengd_ororka[item]
                    print "5 Aldurstengd ororkuuppbot. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
                    print "5.1 Reiknast sem %s prosent af ororkulifeyri." % aldurstengd_ororka[item]


    else:
        print "Sjomennska ekki valin."
        if busetutimi < 40 and aldur >= 67:
            ellilifeyrir = ellilifeyrir * busetutimi/40
            print "0 Busetuskertur ellilifeyrir."
        else:
            print "0 Oskertur ellilifeyrir vegna busetu eda yngri en 67."

        if 2056404/12 < tekjur < 4209764/12 and aldur >= 67:     #Hamarkstekjur an skerdingar
            ellilifeyrir = ellilifeyrir * 0.75  #Ellilifeyrir skerdist um 25%
            baetur = baetur + ellilifeyrir
            print "1 Skertur ellilifeyrir. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
        elif tekjur < 2056404/12 and aldur >= 67:
            baetur = baetur + ellilifeyrir
            print "1 Oskertur ellilifeyrir. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
        else:
            print "1 Enginn ellilifeyrir."

        if aldur >= 67 and tekjur < 2575220/12:
            tekjutrygging = 1289528/12           #Tekjutrygging manadarlega
            baetur = baetur + tekjutrygging
            print "2 Oskert tekjutrygging fyrir ellilifeyristhega. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
        elif aldur >= 67 and 2575220/12 < tekjur < 4209764/12:
            tekjutrygging = 1289528/12
            baetur = baetur + tekjutrygging * (1-0.3835)
            print "2 Skert tekjutrygging fyrir ellilifeyristhega. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
        else:
            print "2 Engin tekjutrygging fyrir ellilifeyristhega."

        if 75 <= ororkuhlutfall and aldur <= 67 and tekjur < 2575220/12:
            tekjutrygging = 1308604/12
            baetur = baetur + tekjutrygging
            print "3 Oskert tekjutrygging fyrir oryrkja. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
        elif 75 <= ororkuhlutfall and aldur <= 67 and 2575220/12 < tekjur < 4209764/12:
            tekjutrygging = 1308604/12
            baetur = baetur + tekjutrygging * (1-0.3835)
            print "3 Skert tekjutrygging fyrir oryrkja. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
        else:
            print "3 Engin tekjutrygging fyrir oryrkja."

        if 75 <= ororkuhlutfall and aldur <= 67 and born > 0:
            barnalifeyrir = 302100/12
            baetur = baetur + barnalifeyrir * born
            print "4 Barnalifeyrir oryrkja. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
        else:
            print "4 Enginn barnalifeyrir oryrkja."

        # Naudsynlegt er ad adili bui einn til ad eiga rett a heimilisuppbot.

        frestunartugabrot = frestun_ellilifeyris / 200

        # Frestunartugabrotid er notad i linunni her a eftir. Deilt er med 2 thvi baeturnar eru haekkadar
        # um 0,5% fyrir hvern frestunarmanud. Deilt er med 100 til ad fa ut tugabrot.

        baetur = baetur + baetur * frestunartugabrot

        # Baetur eru haekkadar i hlutfalli vid frestunartugabrot og thar med fjolda frestunarmanada.

        for item in aldurstengd_ororka.keys():
            for age in item:
                if ororkualdur == age and aldur < 67 and 75 < ororkuhlutfall:
                    baetur = baetur + ororkulifeyrir * aldurstengd_ororka[item]
                    print "5 Aldurstengd ororkuuppbot. Baeturnar eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur
                    print "5.1 Reiknast sem %s prosent af ororkulifeyri." % aldurstengd_ororka[item]

    if byr_einn:
        if tekjur < 2575220/12:
            heimilisuppbot_var = 380028/12
            baetur = baetur + heimilisuppbot_var
            print "6 Oskert heimilisuppbot. Baetur eru nu samtals %s." % baetur
        if 2575220/12 < tekjur < 4209764/12:
            heimilisuppbot_varar = (3800289/12) * (1-0.3835)
            baetur = baetur + heimilisuppbot_var
            print "6 Skert heimilisuppbot. Baetur eru nu samtals %s." % baetur

    if bifreidarstyrkur:
        baetur = baetur + 12587
        print "7 Styrkur vegna reksturs bifreidar. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur

    if maki:
        baetur = baetur + 37739
        print "8 Framfærsluuppbot. Baetur eru nu samtals %s kr." % baetur

    print "Baetur eru %s kr." % baetur
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having lots of attributes, I'd use one dict:

```
self.data = dict(baetur = 0,
                 ororkustyrkur = 1,
                 ororkustyrkur_62 = 2,
                 ororkulifeyrir = 3,
                 ellilifeyrir = 4)
```

Then, after loading the new data from the file:

```
newdata = dict(baetur = 10,
               ororkustyrkur = 20,
               ororkustyrkur_62 = 30,
               ororkulifeyrir = 40,
               ellilifeyrir = 50)
```

you can [update](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) `self.data` with:

```
self.data.update(newdata)
```

---

If you define `input` like this:

```
class Properties:
    '''Calculates the amount of insurance and/or remedies for a person
    when given a certain set of parameters.
    '''
    def input(self, **data):
        self.data = data
```

Then you can still call it like this:

```
prop.input(kt=0, adlur=1, ...)
```

or by using [keyword-unpacking syntax](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/):

```
prop.input(**data)
```